# wp_update_attachment_metadata breaks after 10 files

Tags: uploads

Currently we are rebuilding an old WordPress site. We need to import a lot of images from there. So I copied all directories to the new site, so the paths would be the same.

Now we want to add them to the media library. So I wrote a little script to loop through the folders and do the action.

It works, but only for the first 10 iterations, for the 11th image `wp_update_attachment_metadata()` isn't working anymore (in the media libary the img thumbnail isn't shown), and then the foreach breaks. (I also tried to begin with another folder, it is the same).

It seems like `require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );` is breaking the loop. Without that and without `wp_update_attachment_metadata()` I can echo all the image urls.

By not working I mean: I created a Template for a Page to do this. The Page is also showing not whole (The navigation does, the WP Toolbar and the header.jpg does not) and also in the Media Library only 10 images are showing from the import. So I guess the script is breaking.

Here is the code:

```
$fullPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/wp-content/uploads/';
$scan = scandir($fullPath);

foreach($scan as $sc) {
    if(ctype_digit($sc)) {
        $scArr = scandir($fullPath . $sc);
            foreach($scArr as $s) {
                if(ctype_digit($s)) {
                    $sArr = scandir($fullPath . $sc . '/' . $s);
                        foreach($sArr as $img) {
                            $pattern="/[0-9]x[0-9]/";
                            if(!preg_match($pattern, $img)) {
                                $path = $fullPath . $sc . '/' . $s . '/' . $img;

                                $uploadPath = '/home/preisvo0/public_html/neu/wp-content/uploads/'. $sc . '/' . $s . '/' . $img;
                                echo $uploadPath . '<br/>';

                                        $name = preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', $img );
                                        $filetype = wp_check_filetype($img, null);


                                        if($img != '..' && $img != '.') {
                                            $attachment = array(
                                                'guid'           => $uploadPath,
                                                'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
                                                'post_title'     => $name,
                                                'post_content'   => '',
                                                'post_status'    => 'inherit'
                                                );                                              

                                                $upload_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadPath );
                                                echo "Uploaded »" . $img . "« »" . $upload_id . "« <br />";

                                            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

                                            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $upload_id, wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $upload_id, $uploadPath ) );
                                        }

                            }
                        }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the symptoms of "not working"? Is the script terminated because it exceeds the time limit?

Comment: I updated my question!

Comment: Any errors in debug log?

Comment: No there are no errors :(

Comment: It looks like the execution time limit gets exceeded. And most probably it is - it makes no sense to even try generate all the metadata for all images with one request and probability it will work is pretty low.

Comment: okay, i get that. Can you think of another solution to perform my purpose?

Comment: Why is `require_once` inside your loop?

Comment: I now have it outside, but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is a execution time problem. So I decreased it on the server & am doing the year folder now hardcoded one by one, write the executed images in a json file and only insert those who are not in there... and hope for the best.